# Unity3D Unet ServerDisconnected due to error: Timeout

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am working on a MMO game using UNet. I have a headless server running on Linux Ubuntu hosted on AWS. Clients get connected to it and players can play with each other. After about 15 to 20 minutes all clients are disconnected and server shows the following error:

> Log: connection {} has been disconnected by timeout; address {::ffff:} time {2666259}, last rec time {2660314} rtt {299} timeout {5000} ServerDisconnected due to error: Timeout

As I am new to multiplayer I am unable to figure out what causes it. I am seeing the resources on AWS and everything looks fine.

Following are my timeout settings in NetworkManager:

**Minimum Update Timeout**: 1 ms

**Connect Timeout**: 5000 ms

**Disconnect Timeout**: 5000 ms

**Ping Timeout**: 3000 ms

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the matchmaker there's a limit that if you exceed will drop your connection ([source](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/matchmaker-client-timeout.342745/#post-2216573)).
Also if you are using reliable channel for sending your messages it will disconnect you if it missed any messages.

UNet is a pretty bad choice for MMO and for a networking solution at all due to a lack of documentation and support from Unity. Right now it's mainly used for testing purposes.

Comment: No, I am not using MatchMaker. Regarding MMO, I could not find anything else. Photon server does not support it anymore, uLink is basically dead because it has not been updated for quite a while now.

Comment: Forge Networking is free since tommorow. You can also use built-in RakNet or write your own wrapper and use the newest version of RakNet.
https://developers.forgepowered.com/

Comment: Thank you. I will look into these.

Comment: Forge Networking is one of the best options for creating an MMO btw